# Simple contract interface is reverted

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-debugging

This is an example code taken from [Chainlink](https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/price-feeds) being run on remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract PriceConsumerV3 {
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    /**
     * Network: Goerli
     * Aggregator: ETH/USD
     * Address: 0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e
     */
    constructor() {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
            0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e
        );
    }

    /**
     * Returns the latest price
     */
    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
        (
            ,
            /*uint80 roundID*/ int price /*uint startedAt*/ /*uint timeStamp*/ /*uint80 answeredInRound*/,
            ,
            ,

        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return price;
    }
}
```

However, when calling getLatestPrice(), the following error is outputted:

> call to PriceConsumerV3.getLatestPrice errored: VM error: revert.

Comment: Hey! I assume you're deploying to a local network and that's the reason why your contract doesnt work (it's trying to call a  contract that doesn't exist on your local net), but please for next Qs specify that kind of details right away in the question :)

Answer (score 1):

In this smart contract, the AggregatorV3Interface is available on Goerli network. It means that for using the method related to this smart contract you must deploy it on Goerli network.

In Remix IDE the processing for deploy the smart contract in a specific testnet or mainnet is:

- Select `Injected Provider - Metamask` from ENVIRONMENT dropdown into **DEPLOY & RUN TRANSACTION** section;

[image]

- Then click on `Deploy` button in the same section;
- Click `Confirm` into Metamask notification for deploying smart contract;
- When the smart contract will be deployed, you can see it into `Deployed Contracts`;
- At this point, expand the window and click getLatestPrice() and it will work well.